# Golang - HTML Templating - Range limit

Tags: html, go

I have a slice which I am printing to an html file in go:

```
<ul>
{{range .arr}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
{{end}}
</ul>
```

If `len(arr) > 5`, how do I print only the first 5 elements of the slice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, I should mention that if you're passing an *array* to the template, you're almost certainly doing something weird. Arrays are relatively rarely used in Go. Typically, you would use a *slice*.

The easiest way would be to pass a slice of the first 5 elements of the array when running the template.

If you need the full input in the template for some reason, you could define a function for taking slices, something like this:

```
func mkslice(a []string, start, end int) []string {
    return a[start:end]
}
```

(see [documentation for how to attach functions to templates](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs))

And the template:

```
{{range mkslice .arr 0 5}}
<li>{{.}}</li>
{{end}}
```

You could also use a form of the `range` action with an index.

```
{{range $i, $val := .arr}}
{{if lt $i 5}}<li>{{$val}}</li>{{end}}
{{end}}
```